# Backbone.js documentation sources

Tags: backbone.js, documentation

Are there any good documentation for backbone.js? I am trying to learn it, however reading the official page is not convenient for me because it is not structured well. 
For example reading about Models has some explanation considering the Collections, which are described later. So if there is a well structured documentation which describe everything in a convenient for understanding order, please suggest it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you what are the resources that I used to get a grasp of Backbone (I am a backend developer turned frontend for necessity on a personal project).

[This website](http://backbonetutorials.com/) has nice examples, from basic to advanced, and was pretty easy for me to follow them. Also [these videos](https://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js) are exceptional and proved to be useful for me. Needless to say I am not affiliated to the owners of these resources, I am only bringing my own experience.

Having said that, my current resources for Backbone, now that I "got" it (and delivered a non-trivial project based on it) are the official website and the source code. It is true that the website is non-linear but that will not be a problem when you have digested all its pieces (you will find yourself go there just for a reference). Another story are the little caveats and details that are not written anywhere (official or unofficial docs). For that you need the source code that is [well documented](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html). Backbone, at least for me, had a steep learning curve. All the concepts are known if you did development before, but getting them right with Backbone and JS has been another story. The single most important resource to learn it has been **starting to play with it**! Seriously, you start with a small UI and try to play with events and collections (I used Chrome dev tools directly, no need to set up a real project). Then you grow organically from there.

But I agree that you kinda have to go and look for informations on multiple places...

Comment: I agree, and as you said, official web site is more like for reference. I event didn't think about looking for documentation at the source files. Usually I search them in different places but never in the source code...
The link to the source code documentation you have mentioned in your answer, is it all the code of backbone?

Comment: Yes, that is the full backbone.js source code. Backbone is just one single JS file and it is the one you see in the annotated source link I provided.