# ID assigned to click event not working in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Below is my html and I have given ids to my all `li`'s ..

```
<ul id="color_wrap">
    <li id="block4"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm novice to backbone.js. In my js file and in backbone.view part I have declared my code as shown below.
I have given width and height to that `li` and when I click on it does not work. I want to make all `li`'s clickable please help me where it is wrong, why its not working.
When I click on li having id block4 it should call chooseColor function.

```
var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#search_container"),

    events: {
        "click #block4": "chooseColor",
        "focusout #search_input": "setDefaults"
    },

    chooseColor:function() {
        alert("hi");
    }

});
```

Comment: be sure that these elements are loaded first!

Comment: @Cherniv hey yes my dom gets loaded first

Comment: @Cherniv is my code correct?

Comment: @Cherniv there's no need actually for those elements to be loaded "first". The events are attached to the view itself (`search_container`) and are matched against the target when triggered.

Comment: @Kingisback the code looks correct so the event should fire. Make sure you are actually clicking on it because that markup without content could yeld to zero-sized box. Just a thought, the code looks correct.

Comment: @– namero999 can u please see at this link http://jsfiddle.net/BckAe/2/ here i have mentioned my whole code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BckAe/2), it's not working because you are binding your events to `SearchView` that has `search_container` as root element. `block4` is not a child of `search_container` and will never be matched. I would suggest to create another View that represent `color_wrap`. Your click event, if declared in such a view, will work.

Comment: @  namero999hey do you have any links from where i can learn backbone easily if u have please comment

Comment: @Kingisback I have answered this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915495/backbone-js-documentation-sources/16915825#16915825.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all events added in the `events` block only listen to the element of the view not all elements in the page. So in your case `# block4` is not a child element in the `view.el` element.

Take a look at the [documented source code of backbone](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-130). There can you see that it use jQueries `$el.on` on the views element to bind the events.

Comment: thnx can u please make changes where it needs to be done because i have been trying this for hours as i am new to it facing difficulties ..